# javascript: Base 10 binary to base 10

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take Binary base `10` **actually binary but interpreted as base `10`** and convert it to base `10` ex: `100` interpreted as `1*10^2` but I want to be `4*10^0`

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parseInt(string, radix)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
parseInt('1100', 2) //will be 12
```

Or in ES6 you can use `0b`

```
var foo = 0b1100;
foo === 12; //true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this `var a = parseInt(100, 2);`
Now a = 4;

I mean, if you have number `n` based 10 but actually based 2, then you convert it to based 10, by this: `var a = parseInt(n, 2);`